# How to use subprocess module in Django website

Tags: python, django, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

I am developing a website in Django and I need to run some R scripts in the background thread. But I want this thread to be in another process and not the main one.

Only because whenever I use os.chdir(), a rare error comes stating that manage.py file was not found. So I want to use change directory function for a child process and not the main one.

Comment: Could you give more detail? How the error came out?And what the error looks like? I did not get any error when I used os.chdir() in my view function.

Comment: You can use the subprocess module from the standard library. If you want the background process to run asynchronously, you can look into something like celery or django-channels.

Answer (score 0):

[subprocess.Popen()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) is what you are looking for

Comment: I want to know how a subprocess module works. Complete flow